# Deleting Objects from Coredata

Tags: objective-c, ios, parsing

In my app I have a Place entity that contains reviews and featured objects at the minute my app is constantly refreshing these everytime i parse my xml data which is fine however I need to delete the review and featued objects before they are re parsed. My code is as follows and I believe I need to delete the objects in the parseXML method at the top:

```
-(void)parseXML:(NSString*)xml{


    TBXML * tbxml = [TBXML tbxmlWithXMLString:xml];

    if(tbxml.rootXMLElement){
        [self traverseElement:tbxml.rootXMLElement];

        if(self.tempItem){
            NSLog(@"Ending Application");
           [self configurePlaceChildrenAndSave];  
            [self startGeoCodingQueue];            
        }
    }

}

-(void)fireGeocoder:(BSForwardGeocoder*)g{
    NSLog(@"Begining FGC for %@ (%@)",g.searchQuery,g.metaData);
    [g findLocation];
}




-(void)startGeoCodingQueue{


  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:kGeoCoderInProgress];

    int i = 0;
    BSForwardGeocoder * fgc;

    NSArray * a = [CoreDataBasicService fetchResultsForEnity:@"Place" andSortDiscriptor:@"name" Ascending:YES];

    for (Place * p in a) {

        if(p.latitude && p.longitude)continue;//skip geocoding if location data exists

        fgc = [[BSForwardGeocoder alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
        fgc.metaData = p.name;
        fgc.searchQuery = p.postcode;  

        NSLog(@"gc:%i-%i",i,[a count]);
        if([a count] == i+1){
          fgc.last = YES;  
        }

        float delay = (float)i*kGeoCoderDelay;
        [self performSelector:@selector(fireGeocoder:) withObject:[fgc autorelease] afterDelay:delay];   

        fgc = nil;

        i++;
    }  



  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i] forKey:kGeoCoderCompletedKey];
}


-(void)finishedGeocoding{

  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:[NSDate date] forKey:kGeoCoderlastRanKey];

  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:kGeoCoderInProgress];

  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kGeoCoderNotificationName object:nil];
}

-(void)forwardGeocoderError:(BSForwardGeocoder *)geocoder errorMessage:(NSString *)errorMessage{
    NSLog(@"EX ERROR: GEOCODER FAILED - %@",errorMessage);

    if(geocoder.last)[self finishedGeocoding];

}

- (void)forwardGeocoderFoundLocation:(BSForwardGeocoder*)geocoder
{
    if(geocoder.status == G_GEO_SUCCESS)
    {           
        BSKmlResult *result = [geocoder.results lastObject];            

        if(!result)return;

        //[self.fowardGeocodingQueue setObject:[NSString stringWithString:value] forKey:self.tempItem.name];
        Place * p = [CoreDataBasicService fetchPlaceNamed:geocoder.metaData];

        p.latitude = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:result.latitude];
        p.longitude = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:result.longitude]; 

        [CoreDataBasicService saveChanges];

    //NSLog(@"%@ - %f,%f",p2.name,p2.latitude,p2.longitude);

        NSLog(@"completed Foward geocoding for '%@' (%@) [%f,%f]",geocoder.metaData,geocoder.searchQuery,[p.latitude floatValue],[p.longitude floatValue]);

        if(geocoder.last)[self finishedGeocoding];      


    }
    else {

        NSString *message = @"";

        switch (geocoder.status) {
            case G_GEO_BAD_KEY:
                message = @"The API key is invalid.";
                break;

            case G_GEO_UNKNOWN_ADDRESS:
                message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Could not find %@", geocoder.searchQuery];
                break;

            case G_GEO_TOO_MANY_QUERIES:
                message = @"Too many queries has been made for this API key.";
                break;

            case G_GEO_SERVER_ERROR:
                message = @"Server error, please try again.";
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }




        NSLog(@"ERROR: GEOCODER FAILED - %@",message);

//      UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Information" 
//                                                      message:message
//                                                     delegate:nil 
//                                            cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
//                                            otherButtonTitles: nil];
//      [alert show];
//      [alert release];
    }
}



-(void)configurePlaceChildrenAndSave{
    if(self.tempReviewArray.count==0 && self.tempReview)[self.tempReviewArray addObject:self.tempReview];

    if(self.tempFeatureArray.count==0 && self.tempFeature)[self.tempFeatureArray addObject:self.tempFeature];

    [self.tempItem setReviews:self.tempReviewArray];   
    [self.tempItem setFeatured:self.tempFeatureArray];    

    self.tempReviewArray = nil;
    self.tempReview = nil;
    self.tempFeatureArray = nil;
    self.tempFeature = nil;

    [CoreDataBasicService saveChanges];
    self.tempItem = nil; 
}

-(NSString*)formatKeyForCoreData:(NSString*)elementKey{
    return [elementKey stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""];
}


-(NSDate*)convertStringDateToDate:(NSString*)stringDate{

    NSDateFormatter * df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"DATE:%@",stringDate);
    [df setDateFormat:@"y-M-d'T'H:m:s'Z'"];
    NSDate * d = [df dateFromString:stringDate];
    [df release];
    return d;
}


-(Place*)getPlaceForName:(NSString*)name{
  NSPredicate * pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name = %@",name];            
  NSArray * results = [CoreDataBasicService fetchResultsForEnity:@"Place" WithPredicate:pred andSortDiscriptor:@"identifier" Ascending:YES];  
  return [results lastObject];
}



-(void)traverseElement:(TBXMLElement *)element {

    do {
        // Display the name of the element
        NSString * value = [TBXML textForElement:element];
        NSLog(@"%@-'%@'",[TBXML elementName:element],value);
        // Obtain first attribute from element

        NSString * ele = [TBXML elementName:element];

        if([ele isEqualToString:@"place"]){
            if(self.tempItem){
                //GEOCODER HERE
                [self configurePlaceChildrenAndSave];
            }

            //CREATE NEW CD ITEM HER       

          if(dataBaseExits){

            TBXMLElement * idElement = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"name" parentElement:element];
            Place * p = [self getPlaceForName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[TBXML textForElement:idElement]]];            

            if(p){
              [self setTempItem:p];

              TBXMLElement * reviewsElement = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"reviews" parentElement:element]; 
              if(reviewsElement){
              self.tempItem.reviews = nil;
              [CoreDataBasicService saveChanges];
              [self traverseElement:reviewsElement];
              }

              TBXMLElement * promosElement = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"featured-places" parentElement:element]; 
              if(promosElement){
                self.tempItem.featured = nil;
                [CoreDataBasicService saveChanges];
                [self traverseElement:promosElement];
              }

              [CoreDataBasicService saveChanges];
              continue;

            }
```

Comment: So, are you simply trying to avoid duplications?  Or do you need to completely remove all the data from your persistent store before parsing the incoming XML stream?

Comment: trying to stop duplications preferably

Comment: Two options, depending on the relative number of data in the stream vs in the persistent store.  You could import everything then remove the duplicates after the fact.  Or you could test for uniqueness as each item is parsed.

Comment: what do you think is the best method could you give a code example please?